# Cordova 3.3.1-0.1.2 (Phonegap) plugins doesn't work

Tags: android, ios, git, plugins, cordova

I have a cordova 3.3.1-0.1.2 test project for iOS, where I use the following plugins (`cordova plugin ls`):

```
[ 'com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin',
  'org.apache.cordova.console',
  'org.apache.cordova.device',
  'org.apache.cordova.splashscreen' ]
```

I've added the plugins like this `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device`. In my git repo, I see, that it adds a bunch of files to the `plugins/org.apache.cordova.device` directory, creates a `CDVDevice.h` and a `CDVDevice.m` in my iOS plugin directory, updates the `ios.json`, updates the `*.xcodeproj` file and adds the plugins to my `config.xml` inside `platforms/ios/test-app/config.xml`:

```
<feature name="Device">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVDevice" />
</feature>
```

But when I try to access the `device` or `window.device` property inside JS, it tells me, that `device` is undefined. The weird thing is, that the pushPlugin is present:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
   console.log(device);
   console.log(window.device);
   console.log(window.plugins.pushNotification);
});
```

The `window.plugins` object only lists the `pushNotification` plugin as a property. It's weird, because they are all installed, and during the installation, cordova said, everything was ok.

I'm a little bit confused, about the outdated, and mixed-with-phonegap documentation, but that would be ok, if one of them would work. I also saw a plugin definition, inside a `config.xml` like this

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
```

Can someone explain me, what's the difference? Is the way (with `feature`) that I'm working outdated with cordova 3.3? When I try to use the `<gap:plugin...` format, my app crashes on startup.

So, please help me to fix this, and clear my mind ;)

Comment: Did you run `cordova build` to prepare/compile the code?

Comment: yes, I run `cordova build`, it copied everything to the right directories, but still, the same problems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, none of the answers worked. Luckily, I found the solution in this mailing list:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cordova-dev/201312.mbox/%3CCABiQX1Vat5XvmKkWt=+viL9oXWnOiAz5ee95h8oJp0j4MU9pJQ@mail.gmail.com%3E

There they say, that this is a bug in cordova 3.3.1. In this versions, the plugins get copied into the `.staging` directory of the different platforms.

So, downgrading with npm to cordova 3.3.0 now worked (on Mac OS X):

```
sudo npm remove -g cordova
sudo npm view cordova versions
sudo npm install -g cordova@3.3.0-rc.1
```

And also check, if cordova is maybe installed from phonegap too. If you *only* use cordova, and non of the phonegap features (like remote build), you can safely remove the phonegap package with

```
sudo npm remove -g phonegap
```

**Update**

The current version 3.4.0 works fine, and doesn't have this issues.

Answer (score 2):

plugin definition using `gap:plugin` is for configuring plugins for phonegap build (so you don't need it for local build).

---

As MBillau suggested, the plugins are added to the platform only after you run `cordova prepare ios` (or `cordova build ios` which launches prepare and then builds the project).

When you run prepare, javascript files of the plugin should be copied to the `www/plugins/pluginfullname/www` folder of the `platforms/ios folder`.

If the files are not there it may be an issue with the `ios.json` file being corrupted. In that case, sometimes uninstalling and then re-installing the plugin solves the problem. In some case you have to remove the `ios.json` file, and empty the plugins folder at the root of your project (and maybe allso the platforms folder) and re-install all the plugins.

---

If window.plugins object only lists the pushnotification plugin it is just because it is the only plugin installed in this object :

- `org.apache.cordova.console` is in `console` and `cordova.logger`
- `org.apache.cordova.device` is in `window.device`
- `org.apache.cordova.splashscreen` is in `navigator.splashscreen`

To know javascript object name to use, you have to read the plugin's documentation or look at the js-module/clobbers property in the `plugin.xml` file of the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I looked it up, and everything looks fine. The files are copied to the destination, I have the right names, but still, they aren't available, after the `deviceready` event. I also tried removing the whole plugins, and re-install them again, but no luck. Anything else I could try?

Comment: one file I forgot to mention is cordova_plugins.js inside the www folder in the platforms/ios folder. cordova.js uses this file to enulerate the plugins (it should be built from ios.json). If it doesn't work for your project, I would suggest to clean plugins and platforms folder and reinstall the plugins or try with a new project.

Comment: Hmmm, the `cordova_plugins.js` file is present, and lists all the plugins I've installed. But also with deleting all the plugins, and re-installing nothing works. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From the root of your Cordova project, go into ./platforms/ios/

```
cd platforms/ios
```

In here there should be a ./build folder - this contains previously built packages which Cordova then uses for 'lazy loading' - i.e. so Cordova does not constantly have to fetch files from various locations, it stores them locally instead. However, I have found this to be problematic.

Delete this folder:

```
sudo rm -r build
```

When gone, rebuild your Cordova project:

```
cordova build
```

It should then recreate the build folder but more importantly, your plugins will be listed in `config.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Check you index.html file has the correct `<script></script>` lines.

I had an issue when creating a new project via CLI. The index.html file referenced phonegap.js instead of cordova.js